# Как поместить скролл браузера под хедер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Сделал хедер во всю ширину страницы, теперь он находится поверх браузерного скролла. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы скролл упирался в хедер (находился под ним)?

Comment: можно. Нужно чтоб скроб был у блока под хедером вручную задать.

Comment: А именно с браузерным нельзя?

Comment: Так браузерный. Стандартный. Нужен блок высотой 100vh, внутри хедер и блок, который будет скролиться. Тоже с фиксированной высотой

Comment: Ну реализация с помощением собственного скролла под хедер и скрытием браузерного есть, тольуо что с этим скроллом есть проблема: если на странице контент помещается весь на экране, а потом подгружаются какие-то данные (например график) и данные уже не помещаются на экран, то этот скролл не активируется, то есть он считает, что как бы на экране все уместилось. Это исчезает, если просто перейти на другую вкладку и вернуться на прежнюю. Но я работаю с незнакомым мне проектом (достаточно крупным) и на данный момент просто не знаю где искать в коде решение этой проблемы.